# Ngnix as reverse proxy for Apache name-based vhosts

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, reverse-proxy

I am running several websites on Apache currently utilizing name-based vhosts. All of the sites are on the same server. I would like to add Ngnix on a new server to sit in front of Apache as a caching reverse proxy.

What is the best way to handle the multiple name-based vhosts? Should I simply have Nginx handle the names and run each Apache vhost on a separate port? Or is there a way to just have Nginx pass the hostname to Apache and have apache take care of the domain names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a reverse proxy, Nginx will pass the Host: header for Apache to use. There is absolutely no reason to put Apache vhosts on separate ports.

Answer (score 0):

If all your sites are on the same apache server, you need only apache a [Name-based Virtual Host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html) configuration.